# Both these simple codes in C are identical but I am getting different outputs. Would love some introspection

Tags: c

Both these simple codes in C are identical but I am getting different outputs. Would love some introspection

The output of first code is correct, it is what i was expecting only i don't understand why output changes by commenting a printf statement, but this is simple only i don't understand the logic even after debugging it, the outputs should be same in both codes as they are same, any help on returning array from functions to main and then printing those arrays would help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* func ()
{
    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3};
    printf ("size: %d\n", sizeof(a[2]));
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int *b, c, i;

    b = func ();

    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", *b + i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
size: 4

1

2

3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* func ()
{
    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3};
    //printf ("size: %d\n", sizeof(a[2]));
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int *b, c, i;

    b = func ();

    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", *b + i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
1

1962249430

1962249431

Comment: This code is exhibiting an undefined behavior as `func` is returning an address of a local variable, which is dereferenced afterwards.

Comment: I'm surprised the first one works. It must be some lucky fluke that the out or scope `a` is still there and pointed to by what `func()` returns.

Comment: @BryanT This is exactly the nature of UB...

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://www.slideshare.net/GiorgiMoniava/introduction-to-undefined-behavior-in-c-and-c), for explanation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That should be an answer.

Comment: @aschepler Will do

Comment: Thanks! for introducing me to new concepts. I'll probe into that.

Comment: @Eugene Sh - I'm aware of that, but I'd be curious to look at the asm code and the stack to see just what lucky coincidence made it **appear** to work.

Comment: @BryanT That array is most likely allocated somewhere on stack. The return code is not changing the values, just moving the stack pointer, so the values are still there.

Comment: @Eugene: Yeah, but I'd have expected the subsequent calls to `printf` to overwrite those values.

Comment: @ruakh Yeah, good point.. Well, all interested parties are invited to investigate the assembly :) I will pass..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very good example of UB.
Which is undefined behavior found in c. Certain codes even though not following rules give correct answers. 
But this is a fluke, but not actual answers.
The reason can be anything from "the answers are stored before hand in those address and garbage value is your actual answer" to just "coincidence"

The variable is dereferenced once you come out of loop, try global declaration.

Answer (score 6):

This code is exhibiting an undefined behavior. The function `func` is returning an address of a local variable `a`, which is going out of scope right after the function returns. Then this address, which is not valid anymore is dereferenced in `main` causing unexpected stuff happen.

Answer (score 0):

Once `func` returns, the array `a` *no longer exists*, and any pointer to it (such as `b`) is now invalid.  Obviously, the storage that `a` occupied still exists, but it's now available for other parts of the system to use.  So that storage may or may not be overwritten before you try to dereference `b`.

The behavior upon dereferencing an invalid pointer is *undefined* - it may do anything from work as expected to crash outright.